# MacBook Air Starts up when I close the lid

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, sleep-wake

When I turn off my [MacBook Air](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp617?locale=en_US) running High Sierra by selecting <kbd></kbd> > <kbd>Shut Down</kbd>, then close the lid, the white Apple logo in the lid will come on and I hear the startup chime.

At first I thought that the Power button was pressed by something on the lid when I close it, but that isn't the case.

I've found [only one Support page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7714741) about this, but this doesn't seem to apply to me because I have no error messages.

As a consequence, I can never turn off the computer while the lid is closed - i.e. to travel or put it away - and the battery depletes much faster when I don't use it for a couple of days.

**How do I stop this from happening?**

Comment: I suspect deep system modifications from a third party app may be the culprit. Download and run [Etrecheck](https://www.etrecheck.com). It's a free diagnostic snapshot of your machine for troubleshooting purposes. All personal info. is anonymized. Update your question with the output using a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) link - or the direct output depending on the verbosity.

Comment: Thanks @njboot! Here goes: https://pastebin.com/ALj0DjuP

Comment: @njboot Could you make this an answer? I got rid of a few apps and their respective launch demons (ClamXAV, MalwareBytes, etc), and the problem is gone.

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect deep system modifications from a third party app may be the culprit.

Download and run [Etrecheck](https://www.etrecheck.com). It's a free diagnostic snapshot of your machine for troubleshooting purposes. All personal info is anonymized. Update your question with the output using a pastebin link - or the direct output depending on the verbosity.

Based on the [link provided](https://pastebin.com/ALj0DjuP), uninstalling some of the more intrusive applications listed (and their respective kexts, launchagents, daemons) may be the solution to your issue. Try uninstalling one at a time until the problem goes away.

Comment: how could any app (intrusive or not) have any impact on what happens when the Mac is completely shut down? this seems highly unlikely to me - the operating system and apps aren't running at this point. i believe only a hardware defect could cause the observed problem...

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting the NVRAM and the SMC on your Mac then test it afterwards and see if it still continues.

**NVRAM aka PRAM**
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

> How to reset NVRAM
>
> Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold
>   these four keys together: Option, Command, P, and R. You can release
>   the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to
>   restart.
>
> On Mac computers that play a startup sound, you can release the keys
>   after the second startup sound. On iMac Pro, you can release the keys
>   after the Apple logo appears and disappears for the second time.

**SMC (System Management Controller)** 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

> How to reset the SMC on Mac notebooks
>
> First, determine whether the battery is removable. Most older Mac
>   notebooks have removable batteries. Mac notebooks that have
>   nonremovable batteries include MacBook Pro (Early 2009 and later), all
>   models of MacBook Air, MacBook (Late 2009), and MacBook (Retina,
>   12-inch, Early 2015 and later). Learn more about Mac notebook
>   batteries.
>
> If the battery is nonremovable:
>
> 1. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.
> 2. After your Mac shuts down, press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same
>      time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. If you have
>      a MacBook Pro with Touch ID, the Touch ID button is also the power
>      button.
> 3. Release all keys.
> 4. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
>
> If the battery is removable:
>
> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Remove the battery. If you need help removing the battery, contact
>      an Apple Authorized Service Provider or Apple Retail Store.
> 3. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds.
> 4. Reinstall the battery.
> 5. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.

Comment: I have just tried both solutions and neither worked, after each one I closed the lid and the computer started.

Comment: The next thing I recommend is verifying your EFI and SMC firmware is up to date. You can follow the steps in this article to check this and to download the update if it is not up to date:


EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Macs

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1237

Comment: This is the only difference: the website says "ROM VERSION: MBA31.0061.B07 (EFI 2.3)" Mine says "MBA31.0069.B00" - what should I do?

Comment: Try calling Apple Support and getting the engineers for Mac to look into it. If you are going to call them, make sure that you ask for a senior advisor, they are the ones that get to talk to the Mac engineers.