# Macbook Pro automatically boots with closed lid

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, sleep-wake

I have a Macbook Pro 16" 2019 that automatically boots after I shut it down.

When I shutdown the macbook as per usual (Apple Icon > Shut Down), and close the lid, it will boot up automatically, because I hear the boot sound.
It typically happens when I pick it up, or pick up my backpack and it's inside.

I have tried forcing it off (pressing and holding the fingerprint reader), but it has no effect, it also boots automatically.

I have found [MacBook Air Starts up when I close the lid](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334069/macbook-air-starts-up-when-i-close-the-lid) and tried the solutions proposed there, but none of them worked.

The things I checked are ensuring the power nap feature is off, removing any applications that might have launchd installed (only opengpg), and reinstalling this machine.

One of my hypotheses is that when you pick up the device the touchpad registers movement and boots based off of that, but then this must be a hardware malfunction because nobody else at work has the issue.

I completely wiped the macbook and installed a vanilla version of Mac OSX.

Here is the output of `pmset -g log > ~/beforeshutdown.log`. Full log here: https://exbin.call-cc.be/r/BepaintWaitresses

```
Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: (null)
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Start                 powerd process is started                                                             
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Assertions            Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using Batt(Charge: 69)          
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Assertions            PID 178(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008000 [System: PrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Assertions            PID 99(powerd) Created InternalPreventDisplaySleep "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff" 00:00:00  id:0x0x1000008001 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Assertions            PID 178(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008000 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Assertions            PID 188(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008002 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Assertions            PID 188(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008002 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Assertions            PID 195(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008003 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Assertions            PID 195(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008003 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Assertions            PID 205(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008004 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:43 +0200 Assertions            PID 205(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008004 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:44 +0200 Assertions            PID 212(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008006 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:44 +0200 Assertions            PID 212(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008006 [System: PrevIdle IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:44 +0200 Assertions            PID 218(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008009 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:44 +0200 Assertions            PID 218(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008009 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:10:50 +0200 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler          
2021-10-03 19:10:59 +0200 Assertions            PID 141(hidd) Created UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:10000063c name:NULL product:Apple Internal Keyb eventType:11" 00:00:00  id:0x0x90000809a [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:11:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 466(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008150 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:11:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 466(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008150 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:11:19 +0200 Assertions            PID 520(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008163 [System: PrevDisp DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:11:19 +0200 Assertions            PID 520(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008163 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:12:03 +0200 Assertions            PID 111(mds) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.metadata.mds.power" 00:01:12  id:0x0xb0000804d [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:13:19 +0200 Assertions            PID 99(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventDisplaySleep "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff" 00:02:00  id:0x0x1000008001 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:13:19 +0200 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser kDisp] Using Batt(Charge: 72)          
2021-10-03 19:14:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 401(backupd) ClientDied PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Time Machine backup" 00:03:01  id:0x0x100008127 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:14:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 401(backupd) ClientDied BackgroundTask "Time Machine backup" 00:03:01  id:0x0xb00008126 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          

2021-10-03 19:15:19 +0200 : Showing all currently held IOKit power assertions
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 141(hidd): [0x000000120009809a] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:10000062a name:AppleHIDKeyboardEve product:Apple Internal Keyb eventType:3"  
    Timeout will fire in 120 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

And the output of the same command, after booting automatically: `pmset -g log > ~/aftershutdown.log`.
Full log here: https://exbin.call-cc.be/r/MisteachingTempos

```
Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: (null)
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Start                 powerd process is started                                                             
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using Batt(Charge: 68)          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 179(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008000 [System: PrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 99(powerd) Created InternalPreventDisplaySleep "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff" 00:00:00  id:0x0x1000008001 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 179(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008000 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 189(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008002 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 189(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008002 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 193(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008003 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 193(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008003 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 200(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008005 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 200(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008005 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 208(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008006 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 208(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008006 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 216(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008007 [System: PrevDisp IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:15:56 +0200 Assertions            PID 216(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008007 [System: IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:16:03 +0200 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler          
2021-10-03 19:17:06 +0200 Assertions            PID 141(hidd) Created UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:100000621 name:AppleHIDKeyboardEve product:Apple Internal Keyb eventType:3" 00:00:00  id:0x0x9000080ac [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context127.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x50000808d [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context127.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x10000808c [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context128.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x500008091 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context128.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x100008090 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context129.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x500008095 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context129.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x100008094 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context130.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x500008099 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context130.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x100008098 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context131.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x50000809d [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context131.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x10000809c [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context132.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x5000080a1 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context132.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:01  id:0x0x1000080a0 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context113.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x50000805a [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context113.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x100008059 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context114.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x50000805e [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context114.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x10000805d [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context115.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x500008062 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context115.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x100008061 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context116.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x500008066 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context116.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x100008065 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context117.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x50000806a [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context117.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x100008069 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context118.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x50000806e [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:09 +0200 Assertions            PID 190(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context118.preventuseridlesleep" 00:01:03  id:0x0x10000806d [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:12 +0200 Assertions            PID 458(fsck_apfs) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008162 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2021-10-03 19:17:12 +0200 Assertions            PID 458(fsck_apfs) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "Running FSCK" 00:00:00  id:0x0x500008162 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          

2021-10-03 19:17:20 +0200 : Showing all currently held IOKit power assertions
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   InternalPreventDisplaySleep    1
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 120(apsd): [0x00000056000b8179] 00:00:00 ApplePushServiceTask named: "com.apple.apsd-datareceived-push.apple.com"  
   pid 120(apsd): [0x0000004f000b8166] 00:00:06 ApplePushServiceTask named: "com.apple.apsd-recreatecourierstate-push.apple.com"  
   pid 120(apsd): [0x0000004b000b80b9] 00:00:10 ApplePushServiceTask named: "com.apple.apsd-recreatecourierstate-sandbox.push.apple.com"  
   pid 120(apsd): [0x0000000c000b8089] 00:01:13 ApplePushServiceTask named: "com.apple.apsd-login"  
   pid 111(mds): [0x00000009000b804e] 00:01:16 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds.power"  
   pid 99(powerd): [0x0000000200108001] 00:00:07 InternalPreventDisplaySleep named: "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff"  
    Timeout will fire in 113 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
   pid 141(hidd): [0x00000048000980ac] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:100000621 name:AppleHIDKeyboardEve product:Apple Internal Keyb eventType:3"  
    Timeout will fire in 120 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

Comment: If you think it's a hardware fault, then take it to an Apple Store.

Comment: I know, but I'm asking here first in case I'm wrong. It would save me some days without a machine.

Comment: If you want to fully rule out software create a backup and completely wipe and reinstall the machine (also make sure no Bluetooth devices are paired) and see if the issue still occurs on a vanilla system (before installing any software).

Comment: Can you share an excerpt of your power management logs? Please include all timestamps starting at the last successful "normal" boot and continuing through you closing the lid and the machine subsequently booting by itself. `pmset -g log`